Get ACF custom field value inside wordpress loop
I need to get the value of an acf field that is used on a custom post type. I have readed this question and tried to use the_field function. It worked but that function will ignore my CSS class on the element I have created to manage how the information will appear. I've also used the get_field but it will only return the custom field of a single post and ignore the loop also if i pass the post id. How I can fix this problem?
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        
        $acf_field = get_field('luogo', $post->ID);
    
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id,'full'); 
        
        if($count == 0){
            $lis .= '
            <div class="image-box img-col-1"  >
                <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'" >
                    <span style="padding: 60% 20%;" class="cpt-title"><img src="https://mysite.archi/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/hover_1.svg">'.get_the_title().'<span class="place">'.$acf_field.'</span></span>
                    <img src="'.esc_url($featured_img_url).'">
                </a>
            </div>';
        }else if($count == 1){
            $lis .= '
            <div class="image-box img-col-2">
                <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'" >
                    <span style="padding: 20% 20%;" class="cpt-title"><img src="https://mysite.archi/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/hover_2.svg">'.get_the_title().'<span class="place">'.$acf_field.'</span></span>
                    <img src="'.esc_url($featured_img_url).'">
                </a>
            </div>';
        }else if($count == 2){
            $lis .= '
            <div class="image-box img-col-3" >
                <a href="'.esc_url( get_permalink() ).'" >
                    <span style="padding: 20% 20%;" class="cpt-title"><img src="https://mysite.archi/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/hover_3.svg">'.get_the_title().'<span class="place">'.$acf_field.'</span></span>
                    <img src="'.esc_url($featured_img_url).'">
                </a>
            </div>';
        }
        $count++;   
    endwhile;
    
    wp_reset_query();  
    return sprintf( 
          '<div class="%s">%s</div>',
          esc_attr( $ul_class ),
          $lis
        );


There should be little difference between the_field and get_field, other than that the former writes directly to the output buffer, whereas the latter returns the value. "and ignore the loop also if i pass the post id" - you used $post->ID in that function call, but $post_id in the next one for the featured image - why this discrepancy?

I'm editing the code, honestly I don't know why was used $post_id instead of $post->ID. What I need now is to can place the output in the correct place

Not sure what you mean by that.

I've tried, the value of the variable is the same, it will contain the ID of the post. But what I see is that I will get just the value of the field of one post, other two values that is supposed the function will return are not returned

If it doesn't get the result you were expecting, with the correct post ID - then the most likely explanation would probably be, that you do not actually have a value stored for that post id. Go check in your database to verify.

Into the database it's all stored correctly. As I said, if I use the the_field() function I will get all the informations, but are printed on the screen in the wrong place and I don't have the possibility to place the info correctly.

Can't tell from the outside, why those two should behave differently. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/ explicitly says, "Please note this function is the same as echo get_field()." (Not strictly true any more, since get_field has an added 4th parameter by now, but that should not be relevant to how the value is retrieved in the first place.)

You could use output buffering to capture the output of the_field, so that you can store it into a variable and insert it into your strings afterwards ... Not really a nice solution though.

@CBroe you mean I can use ob_start() ob_end_flush()? can you share an example please?

Basically, not much more than ob_start(); the_field(...); $acf_field = ob_get_clean();- but you got to be careful; if something else might have started an output buffer before already, then you'd need to deal with the multiple "levels" correctly.

I will give a test to this solution, thank you for the suggestion.

@CBroe I'm testing the solution you've suggested. When I do the var_dump I will see that the $acf_field variable contain three strings that are the values I will need to display. At this point I think I need to split the content of the variable?
